# How do you add an icon resource using a numeric name to a TImageCollection?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have a resource file created with visual studio that I'm using with C++ Builder, example entry: `IDI_ICON1 ICON "filename.ico"`

I tried loading it to a `TImageCollection` using the value as in `"101"` as well as `"IDI_ICON1"` since `MAKEINTRESOURCE()` is not available to provide as a parameter, but it doesn't work.  Neither `Add()` works below, says not found.

```cpp
for (UINT i=IDI_USER_ICON_START; i<=IDI_USER_ICON_END; i++) {
    String resname=String::Format("IDI_ICON%u", ARRAYOFCONST((i-(IDI_USER_ICON_START-1))));
    //ImageCollection->Add(resname, reinterpret_cast<NativeUInt>(HInstance), resname);
    ImageCollection->Add(resname, reinterpret_cast<NativeUInt>(HInstance), String::Format("%u",ARRAYOFCONST((i))));
}
```

How do I handle loading the `ICON` resources with a numeric name?

Comment: Have you compiled the text resource (*.res) file to a binary one (*.rc) yet? Have you inspected the rc file with resource inspector tool that it really contains what you expect?

Comment: @DelphiCoder the binary file is `.res`, not `.rc`.  A `.rc` file is a text script that gets compiled into a binary `.res` file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, i just mixed the two types the other way around

Answer (score 0):

[`MAKEINTRESOURCE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makeintresourcew) simply casts an integer value as-is into a character pointer.  This works fine when using the Win32 [`FindResource()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-findresourcea) API directly, since it accepts such a character pointer for a resource name.  But, this does not work for anything that takes a Delphi-style `String` for a resource name, as `String` requires a character pointer to be pointing at a C-style null-terminated string, which is not the kind of pointer that [`MAKEINTRESOURCE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makeintresourcew) returns.

So, to do what you want, you have two choices:

- specify the numeric resource ID in `"#<ID>"` string format, per the [`FindResource()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-findresourcea) documentation, eg:

```cpp
for (UINT i = IDI_USER_ICON_START; i <= IDI_USER_ICON_END; ++i) {
    String imgname = String().sprintf(L"IDI_ICON%u", (i-IDI_USER_ICON_START)+1);
    String resname = String().sprintf("#%u", i);
    ImageCollection->Add(imgname, reinterpret_cast<NativeUInt>(HInstance), resname);
}
```

- if that doesn't work (for instance, if `Add()` expects an `RCDATA` resource instead of an `ICON` resource - I can't verify that right now), then use the overload of `Add()` that takes a `TStream` instead of a resource name. You can then pass it a `TResourceStream`, which has a constructor that takes a numeric resource ID and a resource type, eg:

```cpp
for (UINT i = IDI_USER_ICON_START; i <= IDI_USER_ICON_END; ++i) {
    String imgname = String().sprintf(L"IDI_ICON%u", (i-IDI_USER_ICON_START)+1);
    TResourceStream *Strm = new TResourceStream(reinterpret_cast<NativeUInt>(HInstance), i, RT_ICON);
    try {
        ImageCollection->Add(imgname, Strm);
    }
    __finally {
        delete Strm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah, the "#" was what I was missing, been way to long to remember. I tried looking up various items in the api but none talked about it, obviously didn't look at `FindResource()`

Comment: Still says it can't find the resource `"#101"` and the other method results with `"Invalid Stream Format"`

Comment: I don't have the source code for `TImageCollection::Add()` to see how it opens the resource. That is why I suggested the `TResourceStream` alternative so that you can open the resource yourself. As for the "Invalid Stream Format" error, that comes from `TWICImage::LoadFromStream()` when the WIC API fails to decode the stream data. However, WIC does support decoding (but not encoding) the ICO format, so I don't know why this would fail, unless the resource data is corrupted, maybe. The RTL doesn't expose the error reason, so you will have to debug the RTL to see that error code.

Comment: Are you able to load the resource data into a `TIcon`? If so, then you can `Assign()` that to a `TBitmap`, and then `Assign()` that to a `TWICImage` in the collection.

Comment: This works `TIcon *icon=new TIcon;  icon->Handle=reinterpret_cast<HICON>(LoadImageW(HInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(i), IMAGE_ICON, ImageList16->Width, ImageList16->Height, 0));` so I guess I could try that.  How would I assign so it's all part of the same graphic with different sizes?

Comment: @user3161924 Most graphic formats don't support multiple images, let alone images of different sizes. That is where `TVirtualImageList` comes into play. Fill the `TImageCollection` with a separate item for each "image", where each item has a list of graphics, one for each size. Then attach the `TImageCollection` to a `TVirtualImageList`, and let the ImageList pick the appropriately-sized graphics it wants when it needs them.

Comment: Which method am I using to add these TWICImage items?  I didn't see one that takes it as a parameter ?

Comment: I opened a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75873504/how-do-you-add-an-icon-resource-using-a-numeric-name-to-a-timagecollection

Comment: That link is for this question. Did you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75883513/ instead?