# How do you add TBitmap objects to a TImageCollection at runtime for use with a TVirtualImageList?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I need to load a `TImageCollection` to be used with a `TVirtualImageList` at runtime from `TBitmap` objects.   How do you load them to the collection and assign them so the `TVirtualImage` list will pick the correct graphic for a given index/size?

The background is I need to get Icon resources in to the collection which means assigning a `TIcon` to a `TBItmap` via `Assign()`

I tried this but the test of a `TTreeView` with the `TVirtualImageList` had blank icons so it didn't seem to work (unless I have to do something special with the `TVritualImageList`) - I'm also not sure if I need to `delete` the `TWICImage` object or not:

```cpp
for (UINT i=IDI_USER_ICON_START; i<=IDI_USER_ICON_END; i++) {
    // add new image index item
    TImageCollectionItem *item=ImageCollection->Images->Add();

    // load our icon of the correct size
    TIcon *icon=new TIcon;
    icon->Handle=reinterpret_cast<HICON>(LoadImageW(HInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(i), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0));
    // convert to bitmap
    TBitmap *bitmap=new TBitmap;
    bitmap->Assign(icon);
    // convert to wicimage
    TWICImage *wicimage=new TWICImage;
    wicimage->Assign(bitmap);
    // add a new format for the 16x16 image and add it
    TImageCollectionSourceItem *imageformat=item->SourceImages->Add();
    imageformat->Image=wicimage;

    // now handle 32x32
    icon->Handle=reinterpret_cast<HICON>(LoadImageW(HInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(i), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, 0));
    // convert to bitmap
    bitmap->Assign(icon);
    // convert to new wicimage
    wicimage=new TWICImage;
    wicimage->Assign(bitmap);
    // add a new format for the 32x32 image and add it
    imageformat=item->SourceImages->Add();
    imageformat->Image=wicimage;

    //delete wicimage;
    delete bitmap;
    delete icon;
}
```

Comment: Have you read [Supporting high-DPI images with the Image Collection and Virtual ImageList components](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Supporting_high-DPI_images_with_the_Image_Collection_and_Virtual_ImageList_components) yet? Also, yes, you need to free each `TWICImage` object you create. Though, you don't need to create them in the first place. Change `wicimage->Assign(bitmap); ... imageformat->Image=wicimage;` to `imageformat->Image->Assign(bitmap);`

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't really tell you anything about how to do it in code.  But I found a way that works after messing around a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Start with `AutoFill` on the `TVirtualImageList` set to `false` then after filling the `TImageCollection` you set the `AutoFill` to `true` to fill the image list.

Here's the cleaned up code:

```cpp
// initialize objects to create
TIcon *icon=NULL;
TBitmap *bitmap=NULL;

__try {
    try {
        // create objects needed
        static const int imgformats[]={16,24,32,48,64};
        icon=new TIcon;
        bitmap=new TBitmap;

        for (UINT i=IDI_USER_ICON_START; i<=IDI_USER_ICON_END; i++) {
            // add new image index item
            TImageCollectionItem *collectionitem=ImageCollection->Images->Add();

            for (int iif=0; iif<ARRAYSIZE(imgformats);iif++) {
                // load our icon of the correct size
                icon->Handle=reinterpret_cast<HICON>(LoadImage(HInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(i), IMAGE_ICON, imgformats[iif], imgformats[iif], 0));
                // convert to bitmap
                bitmap->Assign(icon);
                // add a new image for the image format
                TImageCollectionSourceItem *imageitem=collectionitem->SourceImages->Add();
                // copy bitmap over as the new image format
                imageitem->Image->Assign(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception &E) {

    }
}
__finally {
    // clean up as needed
    delete bitmap;
    delete icon;
}

// fill image lists
VirtualImageList16->AutoFill=true;
VirtualImageList32->AutoFill=true;
```